# A javascript code dont work when I use it on a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm starting to use javascript and my problem is that:
I have this code, that works without problems:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list" id="table">
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <script>
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");// Create a <button> element
            btn.setAttribute('type', 'button'); // input element of type button
            btn.setAttribute('value', 'prueba');
            btn.setAttribute('id', 0);

            var t = document.createTextNode("prueba");       // Create a text node
            btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I need to use it more times on the same page. So I tried to add this on a function, like that:

```
<script>
   function prueba(){

        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        .......
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
   };
</script>
```

The problem is when I call this function with:

```
<script>prueba();</script>
```

The code doesn't show any buttons. When the same code is outside a function this works, but when I add this code inside a function, this don't work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where are you calling it head/body/etc? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: From Kevin Bouchers comment.

Your can call it onload like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prueba())

function prueba() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button'); // input element of type button
  btn.setAttribute('value', 'prueba');
  btn.setAttribute('id', 0);
  var t = document.createTextNode("prueba"); // Create a text node
  btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list" id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function when the DOM is ready.

```
<script>window.onload = prueba;</script>
```

Comment: It is better to add an event listener rather than overwriting any registered handlers: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prueba)`